# Display date of the last update in Google Sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets

I want to display the date of a sheets last update but I can not find a way to do this. Is it possible?

Comment: possible only with script. search for "timestamp script"

Comment: This is possible with Google Apps Script. Could you provide a sample spreadsheet and the expected output?